# Mysql in a separate container or in the same

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

So, I am buildin a docker container for a django app and after reading a decent amount on the internet I found out that I can either include in docker-compose.yml an already made image for Mysql or I can include it in the container of the app. I was wondering what are the positive sides of the one and of the other. Is one of them more secure and the other not or does the one work faster than the other?

Answer (score 3):

Containers are just a way to run processes. They have very little overhead. Best practice is to run each type of process in its own container.

As an example, if you want to update your Django app, you would probably want to do that without stopping your mysql database. You'd want to stop your mysql database only in instances like upgrading the version of mysql.

If you run each of these services in their own container, this separation allows your services to not interfere with each other.

Comment: So, both ways are equally safe? Whether I include mysql in the same container as the app or I use a ready image from the docker hub?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. having both your web application and database engine in the same container introduces extra complexity and defeats the isolation that Docker gets you so readily. Keeping them separate is definitely best practice, so I wouldn't call both options equal.